# def function returning wrong value (python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

So Im working with def functions for the first time and the documentation looked simple enough. and got a few examples. However I cant relate it back to my code.
I have 2 files langpy and test1:

test1.py

```
import time
import thread
import os
import sys
import ctypes
import wmi
from langpy import lang
from langpy import port
string = ""

class service_test:
        def __init__(self):
                thread.start_new(self.do_something, tuple())
                while True:
                        if getattr(sys,'stopservice', False):
                                sys.exit()
                        time.sleep(0.3)

        def do_something(self):
                print(str(lang))
                print(str(port))
                while True:
                        fname = 'c:\\\\test.txt'
                        f = open(fname, 'a')
                        f.write(str(time.time()))
                        #f.write("%s /n/r") % string
                        f.close()
                        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        tst = service_test()
```

langpy:

```
import os
import time
import ctypes
import wmi

def lang(self, language):
        windll = ctypes.windll.kernel32
        language = str(windll.GetUserDefaultUILanguage())
        return

def port(self, Ardport):
        Ardport = "not found"
        c = wmi.WMI()
        wql = "Select * From Win32_USBControllerDevice"
        for item in c.query(wql):
                        s = str(item.Dependent.Caption)
                        strfind = "Raptor"
                        if (s.find(strfind) >= 0):
                                Ardport = str(item.Dependent.Caption)
        return
```

I want it to return the strings from `Ardport = str(item.Dependent.Caption)` and `language = str(windll.GetUserDefaultUILanguage())` in the test1 code, but it keeps printing

```
function lang at 0x027479F0
function port at 0x027503B0
```

(they have `<>` on the outside as well but forum format wont include them)

I have an unedited version of langpy (without defining anything) which retunes the correct str

```
import os
import time
import ctypes
import wmi
windll = ctypes.windll.kernel32
lang = str(windll.GetUserDefaultUILanguage())
print(lang)
Ardport = "not found"
c = wmi.WMI()
wql = "Select * From Win32_USBControllerDevice"
for item in c.query(wql):
        s = str(item.Dependent.Caption)
        strfind = "Raptor"
        if (s.find(strfind) >= 0):
                Ardport = str(item.Dependent.Caption)
print (Ardport)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are importing these functions correctly:

```
from langpy import lang
from langpy import port
```

However, you are printing the *reference* to these funtions, not the return value.

```
print(str(lang))
print(str(port))
```

You want to actually *call* the funtion, then print what gets returned.  You can do this like so:

```
print(str(lang()))
print(str(port()))
```

Just one more set of parenthesis!

**EDIT:**  Upon looking further, you also are not returning anything from your functions.  Try:

```
def lang():
            windll = ctypes.windll.kernel32
            language = str(windll.GetUserDefaultUILanguage())
            return language

def port():
        Ardport = "not found"
        c = wmi.WMI()
        wql = "Select * From Win32_USBControllerDevice"
        for item in c.query(wql):
            s = str(item.Dependent.Caption)
            strfind = "Raptor"
            if (s.find(strfind) >= 0):
                Ardport = str(item.Dependent.Caption)
        return Ardport
```

Note:  you will not need argumens for these functions, unless there is some functionality I'm missing.

The `self` argument is used for class methods, so they know which object to refer to.

Comment: Thanks, was just unsure on the print functions from a def function, i was looking into the return statements and couldn't figure which part to return so i left those out.

Comment: The syntax you had was interesting, not valid python, but I have seen other language which do something similar, where `return` already knows what to return based on earlier declarations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the actual value that you want to print from your function. Replace the existing `return` lines in `langpy` with:

```
return language
```

and

```
return Ardport
```

Then you need to `print(lang(my_lang))` and `print(port(my_port))` in your `test1` file. These print statements will then basically read "print whatever is returned by the function call `lang(my_lang)` (or `port(my_port)`)".